# Convergence/divergence of the following series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am trying to figure out if the following series converges or diverges: 
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \log (1- \frac{1}{k} + \frac{1}{k}\cos\theta)$$
but I am not sure how to do this... can someone give me any ideas? $\theta$ is fixed in $\mathbb{R}$.

To provide more context, I am actually trying to figure out if the following product is finite: 
$$\prod_{k=1}^n (1- \frac{1}{k} + \frac{1}{k}\cos\theta)$$
I read somewhere that you can determine whether or not a product is finite by checking that the above series converges/diverges. Is this true?

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

So you have a product $P$, taking the logs of which you get
$$
\ln P
 = \ln \left(\prod_{k=1}^n \left(1- \frac{1}{k} + \frac{1}{k}\cos\theta\right)\right)
 = \sum_{k=1}^n \ln\left(1+ \frac{1-\cos\theta}{k}\right)
 = \sum_{k=1}^n \ln\left(1+ \frac{a}{k}\right)
$$
where $a = 1-\cos \theta \in [0,2]$, so if the RHS converges, then $\ln P < \infty$, which implies that $P<\infty$ as well.

Can you take it from here?

**HINT 2**

Instead of working with the variable $a$, you can note that $\ln$ is an increasing function, so
$$
\ln P
 = \sum_{k=1}^n \ln\left(1+ \frac{a}{k}\right)
 \le \sum_{k=1}^n \ln\left(1+ \frac{2}{k}\right)
$$

**HINT 3**

To characterize the behavior of the sum, you can use the integral test. One way to see this is using $v = 2/x \iff dx = -2/v^2 dv$ and $\ln(1+v) \approx v$ for very small positive $v$, you have
$$
\begin{split}
\int_2^\infty \ln\left(1+ \frac{2}{x}\right) dx
 &= 2 \int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1+v)}{v^2}dv \\
 &= K_\epsilon + 2\int_0^\epsilon \frac{\ln(1+v)}{v^2}dv \\
 &\approx K + 2\int_0^\epsilon \frac{v}{v^2}dv,
\end{split}
$$
which diverges...

Comment: Thanks for your hints. If I use the comparison that ln(1+a/k) > ln(1-a/k) >= -a/k then I think I am getting the conclusion that the series diverges? Is that correct?

Comment: @bilbo with that logic, $\sum \ln(1+a/k) > \sum(-a/k) = -\infty$ but you did not prove anything that way, you need a positive diverging lower bound or converging upper bound. similarly $\ln(1+a/k) < a/k$ does not help since now the upper bound diverges...

Comment: It seems as though you are guiding the OP to bound the term $\ln(1 + \frac{2}{k})$ above by a term whose series is convergent. Is this correct?

Comment: @NicholasRoberts no, just saying this does not work. The sum actually diverges, you can see this using the integral test

Comment: Ok, so then I don't understand you put the inequality in your Hint 2. How does that help showing divergence? Indeed, we can show the right most sum is divergent using the integral test, but then the desired sum is bounded above by a divergent series, which tells us nothing as you stated.

Comment: @NicholasRoberts idea was to show the realistic value for the sum, that you did not have to necessarily work with a variable $a$. Happy to delete it if it was confusing.

Comment: Oh I see. It was more heuristic and not necessarily setting us up to use the comparison test. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @NicholasRoberts yes, exactly, just tried to give some extra insight